# files duplicated for no reason reappear after deleting?

Tags: lubuntu, pdf, copy, duplicate-files

I use Lubuntu 16.04.1

after successfully copying the content (pdf files) of one folder to a new one (both on my external hard drive), I observed that most of the files duplicated in the original folder (same name, same size,...).

When I delete (or cut) one of the duplicated files, the remaining file with the same name turns corrupted, if I restore the dulplicated file it 'merges' with its duplicate without notification and then pdf file opens again without any problem.

I merged like that all duplicated files but when after some time I plugged again my external hard drive, I observed that all those pdf files were duplicated again !

The duplicated files are not corrupted, I can open both of them.

Could you help please ?

PS:I must say that I often use this external hard drive with Windows Vista (!) (dual-boot).

Comment: Hard to say. My guess is impending hardware failure or you removed hte HD before the changes were written to disk, hard to say. How did you delete them ? Are the files corrupted ? did you run sync before removal of the hard drive ? where physically are the files located ?

Comment: The duplicated files are not corrupted, I can open both of them. If I delete files (using 'move to trash') or cut them to another folder on my desktop, I observe the same problem. I didn't use rsync. Files are located at /media/name/HARD DRIVE/FOLDER/. I must say that I use this external hard drive often with Windows Vista (dual-boot).

Answer (score 0):

I ran a scan disk. Many errors were corrected and now my problem is fixed.

I guess it is not entirely safe to work on the same external hard drive with windows and lubuntu.

Comment: You have to disable hibernation in Windows . If the disk is showing errors it may be about to fail.